# How do I create a table in SQL server database in asp.net web application project

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to learn to create database in Visual Studio. I've been following tutorial from here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606540(v=vs.100).ASPX

In my empty asp.net web application project, I created an SQL server database. I'm trying to add a table to the database. I clicked on "Add new table" in Server Explorer window.

I'm unable to do step 6 of "Adding a Table". Because of this I'm unable to follow further instructions. My table "Products" does not appear in the Server Explorer window.

How do I create a table? There's no OK button as in the tutorial.

Here's a snapshot.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: From the Data Tools Operations window on the bottom, it's showing a red X. Did you actually create the table? If not, click the Update button again and click Update Database on the dialog that comes up.

Comment: @ Anthony Chu : I'm not able to create the table itself. If I want to save it, It'll ask the location I'll specify and save it, but In the T-SQL window the small yellow side-bar is not removed which means the table is not saved in the solution. Even If I update it (The Data Tools Operations Window previously did show Everything's fine(Green tick)), yellow side-bar is not removed. Anyhow I don't think that Data Tools Operations window is relevant.

Comment: If you updated it and got a green tick and the bottom window, that means the table was created and you should be able to right click on the `Tables` folder in Server Explorer and see the new table. The instructions you have is for VS 2010 and you're using 2013, that's why it's different. You don't need to save the SQL file. Just close it. You can always get it back by double-clicking the table in Server Explorer.

Comment: @Anthony Chu : I've updated the picture. The situation is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I have yet to find a decent way to manage a SQL database inside of Visual Studio.

Instead, I recommend using Management Studio, it makes everything so much easier:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763 or 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579

Also, here is a guide on how to use it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx